# PHP function - screening array sanity check

Tags: php, arrays, function, filter

I'm writing a function to loop through an array until a match is found based on another array. However the value is returning null.

My example:

```
$i = 1;
$tmp = ['fff'=>111,'aaa'=>100,'ddd'=>99,'ccc'=>87,'eee'=>45,'bbb'=>3,'ggg'=>1];
$prg = ['bbb','ccc'];
function doFilter($tmp,$prg,$i) {                   
    $second = array_slice($tmp, $i, 1);
    $snd = key($second);
    if (!in_array(strtolower($snd),$prg)) {
        $i++;
        doFilter($tmp,$prg,$i);
    } else {
        // echo ccc
        echo $snd;
        return $snd;
    }                   
}
$snd = doFilter($tmp,$prg,$i);
// echo NULL
echo $snd;
```

Any thoughts why the value within the function is not being returned to populate the variable as a response from the function?

Comment: Why are you doing this recursively?  Also, are you just trying to see if 1 `$prg` is in `$tmp` or you want to see all `$prg` that are in `$tmp`?

Comment: You don't return the value from the inner recursive calls.You probably want `return doFilter($tmp,$prg,$i);`

Comment: But really: `array_intersect(array_keys($tmp), $prg)`

Comment: fantastic, thanks! yes, was not returning the recursive loop.

Comment: but yes, there is probably an easier way to do it, although comparing keys in one array to values in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be efficiently done with [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad15968635327012f90f6e19bc6647839fececbd)):

```
$tmp = ['fff'=>111,'aaa'=>100,'ddd'=>99,'ccc'=>87,'eee'=>45,'bbb'=>3,'ggg'=>1];
$prg = ['bbb','ccc'];

echo "1st Key: ",(sizeof($result=array_intersect(array_keys($tmp),$prg))==0?"Not Found":current($result));
echo "\n\nResult Array: ";
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
1st Key: ccc

Result Array: array (
  3 => 'ccc',
  5 => 'bbb',
)
```

Alternatively if you want to get the value of the first match:

```
var_export(current(array_intersect_key($tmp,array_flip($prg))));
// Will ouput: 87
// if no matches, will return FALSE
```